# Restricting printer to only one program

Tags: windows, permissions, printer

In my business, my point of sale program in on Windows, and the application restricts the cashier from opening the drawer. It will open only when a receipt is printed or only a supervisor opens the drawer.

Any one can kick open the drawer by printing a test page or printing any document, as the printer driver will kick open the drawer with any print signal and Windows is running as a local admin.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The way the Print Spooler service runs for Windows, this is not possible. The Print Spooler is available to any programs who are allowed to print.

The way around this is to restrict the POS system to ONLY running the approved program, unless an administrator logs in. If you wrote the software, you could create your own Printer service and turn off the Print Spooler, but that may be more trouble than it's worth.

The POS software will run with permissions of whomever the Windows user is (or Linux or Mac - same principle). If they are allowed to print from within the program, they're allowed to print from other programs. Your only solution is to restrict what programs launch or are able to run when logged in as the POS user.

Answer (score -1):

You may restrict a printer to certain user accounts.
By ensuring that your program runs under a user account that is allowed to use
the printer, while the login account is not permitted this access, you may
effectively make the printer unavailable.

This is the procedure:

- Run *Start >  Devices and Printers*
- Right-click the printer and select "Printer properties"
- In the printer properties window, click on the "Security" tab
- Under the security tab, add or remove user accounts
  (I would suggest not to remove the Administrators and other sensitive accounts)
- Click on Apply and OK.

The
[runas command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11))
might be useful here.